# django importing AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django

I´m trying to use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as a foreignkey in a model, but the "settings" part doesn´t seem to work.

How should I import that?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Tareas(models.Model):
    creador = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, help_text="Estatus del contenido", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import settings as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

**Note:** It's not recommended to import the `User` directly as it won't work in projects where the [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model) setting has been changed to a different user model. Use the [`get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) method instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: For setting a `ForeignKey`, it's actually [recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, since this will play nicely with making migrations. Elsewhere in your code, use `get_user_model()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `from django.conf import settings` to import the django settings.